# GND connections and ground plane routing?

Tags: ground, altium, routing

When I let Altium do autorouting and then I define a ground plane using a polygon connected to my ground pin, I often get layouts where a GND line is flanked on both sides by the GND polygon, and then at the ends, both connectors are connected to the GND polygon:

[image]

Is this actually good layout for a ~10-50 MHz circuit? Would it be between to get rid of the gaps between the two grounds (image center) and have the ground plane be continuous?  That way there is more conductive material, and the left and right GNDs have a shorter path between them.

Comment: 1 - Don't use the autorouter in general. 2 - You can configure the polygon to pour over all same net objects (including traces).

Comment: You may think it's a GND line, but your netlist says otherwise. "NetC1_2" != "GND" ...

Comment: If they really are on the same net, there's a polygon setting called "pour over same net" or something like that, but all the green error markers make it look to me like you have your nets confused.

Comment: No, this is NOT "actually good" layout, basically for anything.

Comment: C1_2 is absolutely GND.  In this circuit there is just a power connector with pins 1, 2 ... I did not realize there was a way to tell Altium that one was specifically GND.  Should I be doing that? 

Do I understand correctly that I should tell Altium to just pour over the nets like so:

https://i.imgur.com/m0aQnS6.png

Comment: @user1850479 - yes, although that will not solve any issues created by the arbitrary auto-routing - its less bad if you at least placed the components manually in a way that makes some sense. In the schematic editor you can add power ports for GND to name a net or place net labels (press P then N) for signals, etc.

Comment: Thanks, I am new to Altium and did not notice that. I realize the autorouting is terrible, I usually go back and redo the worst parts by hand.

Comment: Not much of an answer here but IMHO, take the Altium auto-router up to the North Pole, chop a hole in the ice and throw it in.

Answer (score 1):

Those are thermal relief connections to the ground plane to improve soldering. They won't create any problems as far as high frequencies go. You could change the settings in Altium to flood over those pads, whether that would create a solder problem depends on your board stackup and assembler's soldering process. I avoid ground planes on outer layers because they generally create broken areas of ground that could possibly radiate. Solid ground planes on inner layers are a better option IMO.

Comment: I think you misunderstood his question.  He is asking why the ground plane pour doesn't connect to the traces.

Comment: OK, but doesn't make any sensre to route a ground trace in an area of a ground pour.